# Number of possible arrangements of n discrete data items, with a mean of x.

Tags: means

I was wondering if there is a formula for calculating the number of unique arrangements of a discrete data set of **positive integers** of size $n$, that result in a given mean of lets say $x$. I stress positive integers as I imagine if we allowed for negative values the number of combinations would be infinite, and if we allowed for non-integer values the same situation would arise.

I have little experience in notation of multivariate functions, but I believe in mathematical terms this is what I am looking for:
$$c = f(x,n)$$
Where, $x$ is the given mean, $n$ is the number of data items, and $c$ is the number of unique arrangements of the data set size $n$ that have a mean of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the mean and the nunmber of integers, you're also specifying the sum, so you're basically just asking for the number of ways to partition a given sum $nx$ into $n$ positive integers. Depending on whether you want to distinguish the partitions by order, this is either the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) or a standard [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one) count of $\binom{nx-1}{n-1}$.